# Media items hogging pretty permalinks

Tags: permalinks, uploads, media, media-library

I have a WordPress installation setup but I'm having trouble with items uploaded to the media library taking up pretty permalinks. The only way to fix it that I've figured out so far is to delete the image from the library. However the image in question is used all over the site so I would much rather find another solution.

**Example:**

Say I upload an image called `foo.jpg` then make a page called `foo`, the pretty permalink for the page becomes `/foo-3`. If you try and change it, it reverts back to 3, unless you use something that isn't 'taken'. If I navigate to `url.com/foo` I get the attachment page for the image and not the page.

I've tried changing the permalink settings to all the different settings. I've also tried renaming the image 'title' but that is no good either.

Is there anything else I can do to force the permalink?

Thanks

Comment: I can't get you what you want to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not your permalink settings, it's the fact that `foo.jpg` was uploaded first and "stole" the slug `foo` - you need to change it to something else, *then* set your page slug.

Go to Media > `foo.jpg` > Edit (if you are in grid view, you need to go to "Edit more details")

[image]

From this page you can edit the permalink/slug (just like pages/posts, right beneath the title field) and set it something that isn't `foo`.

Now go re-save your page with slug `foo`.

Comment: Thanks, I completely forgot about this edit screen! However, next issue there seems to be no edit button for the permalink. On another WordPress installation I can see it, but on my local dev and a remote dev site I can't see it. Any ideas?

Comment: Nevermind, I was able to get around it be turning on the slug checkbox in the Screen options section and then edit it there. Thanks though!

Comment: For me I couldn't change the slug on the permalink either - the problem was that the *name* of the media item (at the very top) was blocking my permalink. Changing that fixed it.